# How do I end dictation without using my mouse, and without triggering unintended shortcuts?

Tags: accessibility, voice-dictation, speech

As far as I know, to terminate hands-free voice dictation mode one must use their hands -- either by clicking 'Done', or by pressing Command + D.

However, pressing Command + D also executes the application shortcut associated with that key combination. (eg, in a web browser you trade your dictation dialog for a bookmark dialog)

How can I end dictation mode using my voice?

Is there an official way to exit dictation without using a mouse?

Is there a way to return to Speech Commands once I've successfully used Speech Commands to start dictation mode? (eg, to get the words 'Computer, open Calendar' to open the calendar like usual instead of merely typing those very words into the document in focus)

Comment: I just reconsidered a though of mine based on one of @Mateusz Sloszek's tidbits: do you suppose the Control + D doesn't actually press 'Done' after all but rather it is the opening of the Bookmarks window that automatically closes voice dictation? (since window focus changed -- one of the ways voice mode exits as mentioned)

Comment: Yes, this is true. fn is the shortcut for pressing Done—other shortcuts pass to the application which finishes dictation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible to close dictation using voice command. From Apple page: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5449?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

> When finished, click Done or press the fn key again. Your spoken words then appear in the text field.

The same is for **Enhanced dictation**

> Enhanced Dictation automatically stops listening when you switch to another window, or if you press the Fn key again, or when you click Done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to Apple dictation… you can get it to stop listing to you by saying the words "stop listening"

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18400?locale=en_US

Note:   Before you can use any spoken commands, you must turn on Dictation and Enhanced Dictation in Dictation preferences.